# Cannot parse JSON (SwiftyJson) from Get to my Web API

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

13.12.2017: PLEASE jump to "Update 3" as I have changed my function !!!

---

from an HTTP Get to my Web API I am getting a JSON response and I need to display the data row by row in a `TableViewController`. But the output is empty, as I think that I am not properly able to get `stdata` out of data_list. I assume I am doing something wrong with types?

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
func extract_json(_ data: Data){

    // added for UPDATE 2
    let string = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(string)

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments])
        let data_list = json as? [AnyObject]

        for stdata in data_list! {
            if let StMsgID = stdata["MsgID"] as? String {  // for UPDATE 1: set breakpoint to this line
                if let StSerial = stdata["Serial"] as? String{
                    TableData.append(StMsgID + " : " + StSerial)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})
}

func do_table_refresh()
{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

This is `JSON` when I display it in the debugger:

```
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : [{"CreatedAt":"01-11-17 10:46","MsgID":"ST88”,”Serial”:”88”},{“CreatedAt":"03-12-17 21:35","MsgID”:”ST99”,”Serial”:”99”}]
```

And this is **data_list**:

```
▿ Optional<Array<AnyObject>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    - 0 : [{"CreatedAt":"01-11-17 10:46","MsgID":"ST88”,”Serial”:”88”},{“CreatedAt":"03-12-17 21:35","MsgID”:”ST99”,”Serial”:”99”}]
```

I would expect to see two rows in the TableViewController:

```
ST88 : 88
ST99 : 99
```

What I am getting is an empty table.

Thank you in advance!!!

UPDATE 1:

When I set the breakpoint to line:

```
if let StMsgID = stdata["MsgID"] as? String...
```

I can see the below value, when I drill down into "stdata" -> 0x... -> NSMutableString -> NSString -> NSObject -> isa:

```
[{"CreatedAt":"01-11-17 10:46","MsgID":"ST88”,”Serial”:”88”},{“CreatedAt":"03-12-17 21:35","MsgID”:”ST99”,”Serial”:”99”}]
```

Is it parsed correctly as I still do see both data sets? At this point I would expect to see only the first data set with ST88.

UPDATE 2:

Added the below code to the top of my function:

```
    let string = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(string)
```

The output is:

```
Optional("[\"[{\\\"CreatedAt\\\":\\\"01-11-17 10:46\\\",\\\"MsgID\\\":\\\"ST88\\\”,\\\”Serial\\\”:\\\”88\\\”},{\\\"CreatedAt\\\":\\\"03-12-17 21:35\\\",\\\"MsgID\\\”:\\\”ST99\\\”,\\\”Serial\\\”:\\\”99\\\”}]\"]")
```

==================================

UPDATE 3:

I have changed my code to use SwiftyJson but still cannot get it working.

This is now the latest format I am using, below the response from my Web API:

```
["{\"inbox\":[{\"CreatedAt\":\"01-11-17 10:46\",\"MsgID\":\"ST88\",\"Serial\":\"88\"},{\"CreatedAt\":\"03-12-17 21:35\",\"MsgID\":\"ST99\",\"Serial\":\"99\"}]}"]
```

As per jsonlint.com this is valid.

This is my new function with SwiftyJson in Swift 3:

```
// using SwiftyJSON !!!
func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{
    do
    {
        let json = try JSON(data: data)

        for obj in json["inbox"]
        {
            let value = obj["MsgID"].string // error here (not compiling)
            print (value)
            TableData.append(value)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})
}
```

I would expect to see:

```
ST88
ST99
```

It´s not even compiling, the error I am getting for line

```
let value = obj["MsgID"].string
```

is:

```
Value of tuple type '(String, JSON)' has no member 'subscript'
```

Comment: What does `do_table_refresh` do? Please include its implementation in your question. Some general advice: when you have nested `if` statements without `else` branches, you can merge them into a single statement separating the conditions with commas (`if let StMsgID = stdata["MsgID"] as? String, let StSerial = stdata["Serial"] as? String {...}`). Moreover, the compiler automatically synthetise an `error` variable in the  `catch` block, so you don't need to declare one and especially don't need to cast it to `NSError`. Just do `catch {print(error)}`

Comment: Thank you for the side recommendations. I have added the requested parts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually check that `TableData.count` is not 0 when you call `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: Isn´t this a result due to a problem before? See also UPDATE 1.

Comment: could you post the actual data, as a string. `let string = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(string)`

Comment: @Johnykutty I have added this to the top of my function and this is the output:

`Optional("[\"[{\\\"CreatedAt\\\":\\\"01-11-17 10:46\\\",\\\"MsgID\\\":\\\"ST88\\\”,\\\”Serial\\\”:\\\”88\\\”},{\\\"CreatedAt\\\":\\\"03-12-17 21:35\\\",\\\"MsgID\\\”:\\\”ST99\\\”,\\\”Serial\\\”:\\\”99\\\”}]\"]")`

Comment: Have you tried the new `JSONDecoder().decode` instead of `JSONSerialization`? There are several YouTube videos and tutorials that go over this. I can provide links, if useful and allowed.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Thanks but for that I would need to convert the whole project to Swift 4, right?

Comment: @Romeosan true, but I didn't see what version of Swift you're using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `let data_list = json as? [AnyObject]` to `let data_list = json as? [[String: Any]]`.

---

UPDATE:

The json returned from you webserver is technically valid json, but it's not what you want. The current json returned is a list of strings, what you want is a list of objects.

You need to update your webserver to remove the first `"` and the last `"`.

- `["{\"inb...` needs to be `[{\"inb`
- `...99\"}]}"]` needs to be `99\"}]}]`

I'm guessing that all the `\` are just extra info because you have printed it in the debugger. However if you are getting these `\` from the webserver, then you need to remove these as well.

Comment: When I use `json as? [[String: Any]]` data_list is nil and it is crashing... And when I do `json as! [[String: Any]]` I am getting: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b552d040) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b552db80). At this time json in the debugger is: ▿ 1 element - 0 : [{"CreatedAt":"01-11-17 10:46","MsgID":"ST88”,”Serial”:”88”},{“CreatedAt":"03-12-1‌​7 21:35","MsgID”:”ST99”,”Serial”:”99”}]

Comment: How does the json look like before it enters the iOS app? Can you try to use Postman or something similar to get that raw json? 
http://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: I am now trying with SwiftyJson, I have also posted the latest json. Please see UPDATE 3.

Comment: @Romeosan the real problem is the json returned from your backend. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great, this was the problem. My c# web api was returning as string, after changing the return type to HttpResponseMessage as "application/json" I got rid of the quotes. Now I am returning objects and parse them starting with [[String: Any]]. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your `json` the route element is an array which contains array of dictionaries(array of array).  So,If you need to extract values as described, you should take first object of the root array then iterate over it.Means something like:

```
let data_list = json as? [[[String: Any]]]
```

Instead of

```
let data_list = json as? [AnyObject]
```

In your current implementation inside the for loop, `stdata` is an array.

Comment: Thanks but also this doesn't work, data_list was nil so now I am trying with SwiftyJson. Please see UPDATE3.